# Postioning Objects in HTML (Div/CSS)

Tags: css, html

I'm new to this stuff and trying to design a mock car sales website for a project, but I need some help, bearing in mind a beginner, I have designed a basic layout with `divs`, and I want to put a badge in the top right of the banner, but the logo went in fine using the following and CSS:

```
img.logo
{ 
  position: relative; 
  top:15px; 
  left: 24px;
}
```

But when I try to put in a "badge" in the right hand side it moves the logo? 
[image]

Anyknow know how to keep them both on the same line, also in general whats the best way to postion elements within a webpage? CSS or seperate divs?

Answer (score 0):

when using different div's you should use `float:right;` and `clear:both;` in the next element. 
but try to set it as a background-image:
`background-image:url('./url/to/file.png');`
`background-repeat:no-repeat;`
`background-position:right;`

to answer your general question: both!
use div's and position them with css.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the knowing the html but I would look at display:inline-block and float:right

Answer (score 0):

CSS is cascading style sheets, and it is a styling language. A div is a tag belonging to the markup language HTML.

I would encourage you to follow tutorials on both css and html. There are a gazillion online. Also, make sure you learn how to inspect web pages and view source, so you can learn from what others have done. Best of luck in your endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
img.logo
{ 
position: absolute; 
margin-top: 100px; 
margin-left: 100px;
}
```

just change the value of margin-top and margin-left until you place it on your desired position. you can also use negative ex. -100px;